# SUM() the results of GROUP BY column

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 'volcado': id, reserva, cantidad

With the following query:

```
SELECT (CASE
         WHEN sum(cantidad) > 0 THEN 1
         WHEN sum(cantidad) <= 0 THEN 0
       END) AS suma 
FROM volcado
GROUP BY reserva
```

The result is:

```
╔══════╗
║ suma ║
╠══════╣
║  1   ║
║  1   ║
║  0   ║
║  1   ║
║  0   ║
╚══════╝
```

I need the result of the query would be: 3

How can I SUM() the rows of 'suma' on the same query?

I don't get it run with:

```
SELECT SUM(SELECT (CASE
        WHEN sum(cantidad) > 0 THEN 1
        WHEN sum(cantidad) <= 0 THEN 0
      END) AS suma FROM volcado GROUP BY reserva)
FROM volcado
```

Error:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
SELECT SUM(a.suma) from 
    (SELECT (CASE
        WHEN sum(cantidad) > 0 THEN 1
        WHEN sum(cantidad) <= 0 THEN 0
        END) AS suma FROM volcado GROUP BY reserva)a
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, use the subquery as a table instead of as a column.

```
SELECT SUM(suma) from 
    (SELECT (CASE
        WHEN sum(cantidad) > 0 THEN 1
        WHEN sum(cantidad) <= 0 THEN 0
        END) AS suma FROM volcado GROUP BY reserva)
```

Comment: I think you have added an unuseful from volcado, remove it

Answer (score 0):

> You can use CTE:

```
;WITH cte AS
  (SELECT CASE
              WHEN sum(cantidad) > 0 THEN 1
              WHEN sum(cantidad) <= 0 THEN 0
          END suma
   FROM volcado
   GROUP BY reserva)
SELECT sum(suma)
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query, if you like.  So, instead of using `case` use `having`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT reserva
      FROM volcado
      GROUP BY reserva
      HAVING SUM(cantidad) > 0
     ) r;
```